# Button is not displayed - android

Tags: android, button

The button is not displayed on the screen.

Here's the XML code (the button code is in lines 21-26):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/movies">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:text="Movies"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:text="Click the button to go to the movie list"
        android:textAlignment="center">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the result:
[image: result]

How can I make the button appear on the screen?

Comment: your text view has taken the complete screen the height is set to match parent update it some specific height or use wrap content u should see the button

Comment: use layout weights.

Comment: If you want the TextView to take up most of the screen and the button to be at the bottom, then you could use RelativeLayout instead of your LinearLayout and set the TextView to have android:layout_above="@id/button", where the Button has android:id="@+/button" and has a fixed height. Maybe something more than 2dp though, since that is tiny.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty clear, read this [element's size](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams#constants_1)

Using `match_parent`, your view will take all the height of the parent, there is no place left for your button.

```xml
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:text="Movies"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">
    </TextView>
```

[image]

Use `wrap_content` instead! Or set it height at a specific value.

```xml
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:text="Movies"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click the button to go to the movie list"
        android:textAlignment="center">
    </Button>
```

[image]

I suggest you to use [ConstaintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout?authuser=1) which will give you better UI handling.

BTW, you sould not set the text hardcoded, please use `@string/xxxx` More info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource)